# Javascript bookmark working in windows but not mac

Tags: javascript, macos, bookmarklet

I have a Javascript bookmark that, if pressed while on a certain website, will open the corresponding content editing node in the content management system, which works fine on my computer Google Chrome(Windows). However, when I try it on a Mac system Chrome, the bookmark does nothing, and I am unsure why. I have checked and made sure that Javascript is enabled on the Mac, but it is still not working.

Bookmark:

```
javascript:function url() {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("website.com") > -1){
    var x = VARIABLE["node"];
    if(x == 0)
        alert("No node in the CMS.");
    else
        window.open('https://www.website.com/node/' + x + '/edit');
}
else
    alert("This bookmark is only for usage while on website.com");
}url();
```

Comment: Any console JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 1):

I can get your code to run in chrome on osx.

A couple things about chrome on osx that I've noticed.   When you paste that snippet into the address bar, it automatically strips off the schema "javascript:"  and fires off a search to google.  After that, when you fix that in the address bar while on the subsequent page, it doesn't seem to run at all.

I got the above to work by:

1. Copying it.
2. Creating a brand spanking new window/tab.
3. Pasting the js in the address bar
4. going to the beginning of the address bar and adding the 'javascript:' back on
5. Hitting enter.

It's quite a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into Developer console (F12), and run a function like:

```
javascript:function foo(){
console.log('hi');
}
foo();
```

And report back the output.